# I want to update user profile

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I want to update only those fields those keys I have passed other data should be unchanged but in my case the key I have passed that changes others are set to `null`

```
import userModel from '../../models/usermodel'
import {Request,Response} from 'express'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

const editprofile = (req:Request,res:Response)=>{

    let newData = new userModel(req.body)

    const userObj = {
        email: req.body.email || null,
        first_name: req.body.first_name || null,
        last_name: req.body.last_name || null,
        dob: req.body.dob || null,
        phone: req.body.phone || null,
        gender: req.body.gender || null,
        // profile_img: req.file.filename || null
    };

    userModel.findByIdAndUpdate({'_id':req.body._id}, { $set: userObj }, { upsert: true, new: true })

    .then(result=>{
        res.status(200).json({success:true,message:"Profile Updated",customer:result})
        console.log('result',result)
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.status(404).json({success:false,message:"Something went wrong",error_message:err})
    })
}
export default editprofile
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a loop to populate the given fields:

```js
  let newObj = {};
    Object.keys(req.body).forEach(function(prop) {
        newObj[prop] = req.body[prop];
    });
```

OR

Use findOne() to get the record fields by doing:

```js
  let query = { $set: {} };
  for (let key in req.body) {
    if (customer[key] && customer[key] !== req.body[key])// if the field we have in req.body exists, we're gonna update it
      query.$set[key] = req.body[key];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to update one or more `key` fields, then you should send only the key-value pair(s) which you want to update.

In your code, you are sending the total object in the query.

So, if you want to update `first_name` and `last_name` then send `first_name` and `last_name` only,

```
const userObj = {
        first_name: req.body.first_name,
        last_name: req.body.last_name
 };
userModel.findByIdAndUpdate({'_id':req.body._id}, { $set: userObj }, { upsert: true, new: true }
);
```

That will not update other values.

You can also have a function to remove `null` value keys before the update so it won't replace the original data.

Comment: No I want to update only those value whose key's I have passed.

Comment: yes, same for one or more that one, send only that fields you want to update.

Comment: I think you are not understanding I am making website and it is upto user which values should he want to update

Comment: Yes, but API is in your hand, your code needs to understand that what he wants to edit, and update only that field in the database, not everything. As query won't work that way.